# Purge varnish(4) cache

Tags: varnish

How purge all cached pages on a v4 varnish server ? I found [this](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/whats-new/upgrading.html#invalidation-with-purge) in documentation but how apply the *vcl_recv* command ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return(purge)` will only purge the hash associated with the request object as it currently stands.  What you're describing is a full cache clear.  The easiest way to do that is simply to restart Varnish.  Failing that, you can also use `varnishadm` to ban out all URLs, or write a bit of VCL (see https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/purging.html) to allow you to do the cache clear via a Web request.